# :use via Neo4j Python driver

Tags: python, neo4j, fastapi

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

load_dotenv()
uri=os.getenv("uri")
user=os.getenv("user")
pwd=os.getenv("pwd")

class database(BaseModel):
    db:str

def connection():
    driver=GraphDatabase.driver(uri=uri,auth=(user,pwd))
    return driver

app=FastAPI()

@app.post("/selectdb")
def selectdb(database:database):
    driver_neo4j=connection()
    session=driver_neo4j.session()
    query = f":use {database.db}"
    result = session.run(query)
    return {"response: You have selected the database: " + database.db}
```

Is it not possible to make a query with :use in the Python Neo4j Driver, or have i done something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Commands that start with a colon, like `:use`, are special commands that are understood only by the neo4j Browser.

When using a neo4j driver, you specify the name of the database you want to use when creating a Session. For example, see the `with` clause in [this Python driver sample](https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/query-simple/#_read_from_the_database), which I excerpt here:

```
with driver.session(database="neo4j") as session:
    records, summary = session.execute_read(get_people)
    .
    .
    .
```